# Most performant selection method

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I'm working on a genetic algorithm concerning a ***timetabling problem***, and I have the problem of deciding which selection method I should choose.

My questions are:

**1)How the choice of a selection method can affect the performance of a genetic algorithm?**

**2)What is the most performant method of selection?**

**3)What happens if I try to use a random selection to evade fitness-based  selection (because this task in my case takes time)?**

Thank you in advance ..

Comment: 3) an unsteered random walk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your fitness function, mutation/crossover operators, and overall search space are intimately and subtly interconnected.  Each problem/selection-method will have it's own performance characteristics.  So, there are no definitive answers to your question.  This is still an open research question.

2) Can't say because of 1). You'll have to try, measure, & see for yourself.

3) Probably a complete random walk as ziggystar suggests, but that could be ok.

Comment: concerning your 3th answer in which case it could be ok ?
and thank you very much to your good answers

Comment: When is a random walk good? In genetic algs, people talk of the explore/expliot tension. Sometimes you need to exploit, sometimes you need to explore. The best way to explore, is a random walk.  For example, the best strategy for the needle-in-the-haystack problem is a random walk.

Comment: @Ray But if you never turn the lever towards exploitation, you're unlikely to find a good solution. And exploration for GA is only useful as long as the algorithm remembers something about it. This capacity is limited by the population size. And without selection, you use this capacity equally for the (more prevalent) bad configurations and for the rare good configurations. So I think your exploration capacity is exhausted rather quickly.

Comment: Hey @ziggy.  I don't want to imply that one should always use a random walk. Again, it all depends on the problem.  I was just illustrating that in some (degenerate but not unrealistic) cases, a random walk is (surprisingly!) the best strategy.  In these cases memory, pop size & selection don't matter at all.  It's useful to keep this in mind when tweaking a GA.

Answer (score 1):

In most of the cases I use random selection or binary tournament, but my population model is Steady-State (the offspring replaces the worst if better than this one - so I already perform a selection for survival there).

Random selection ensures that I don't have a very fast convergence. If I increase the selection pressure (for instance q-tournament, q > 2) I get a very fast convergence, which is not good for difficult problems.

Q-tournament is also very easy to implement: Just select randomly q individuals and the best of them is the result of the selection. If q == 1, then you have random selection.

If you have trouble implementing this, you can have a look to my implementation: http://mepx.org/source_code.html (I did it for a variant of Genetic Programming).

Comment: you said :"  If I increase the selection pressure (for instance q-tournament, q > 2) I get a very fast convergence, **[[which is not good for difficult problems]]**. i don't much understund the last sentance can you explain it ?
and thank you in advance

Comment: First of all: what is a difficult problem? A difficult problem is the one which has a large search space with many local optima. What we want to find is the global optima, not the local one. In a genetic algorithm we have a population of individuals, some being better than others. If the problem is difficult, most likely the good individuals are closer to local optima than the global optima. If the selection pressure is high, you will mostly select individuals being closer to local optima and the algorithm with converge there. So, better keep selection pressure low to avoid falling local optim